# Add percentage of total to dict in list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dicts. I'd like to add a new `key` to each `dict` with the name `"percent_total"`, which will state the percentage that the specific `dict` has, compared to the entire list of `dicts.

How can I add a new key with this percentage in the most efficient method possible?

Thank you!

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {
        "name": "Val 1",
        "index": 0,
        "value": 80,
        
    },
    {
        "name": "Val 2",
        "index": 1,
        "value": 12,
        
    },
    {
        "name": "Val 3",
        "index": 2,
        "value": 19,
       
    },
    {
        "name": "Val 4",
        "index": 3,
        "value": 40,
        
    }
]
```

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
total = float(sum(d['value'] for d in l))

for d in l:
    d.update({'percentage': 100.0 * d['value']/total})
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about this approach's efficiency since it creates a new list, but I find it to be clear and succinct, partly thanks to Python 3.9's new way of combining dictionaries:

```
>>> total = sum([i["value"] for i in list_of_dicts])
>>> [d | {"percent": d["value"] / total * 100} for d in list_of_dicts]

[{'name': 'Val 1', 'index': 0, 'value': 80, 'percent': 52.980132450331126},
 {'name': 'Val 2', 'index': 1, 'value': 12, 'percent': 7.9470198675496695},
 {'name': 'Val 3', 'index': 2, 'value': 19, 'percent': 12.582781456953644},
 {'name': 'Val 4', 'index': 3, 'value': 40, 'percent': 26.490066225165563}]
```